# Adding the result of a query (EF) into a string List from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display a list in a Kendo grid.

This is where I select put the values from Db into a list

```
public ActionResult ShowUsers([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ViewModel vM)
{
     try
     {
         using (var db = new Entities())
         {
              var result = (from x in db.Table where x.Id.Value == vM.Id orderby x.Id select new { x.Name }).ToList();
              return Json(result.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

can I do something like this: `vM.ListINeed.Add(result)`  ?

```
public List<string> Users { get; set; }
```

And I want to display it as a column in Kendo. is there a workaround for this? I know that the `vM.ListINeed.Add(result)` is not allowed, because result is a list of type`<Name>` or so.

Comment: [List<T>.AddRange method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/z883w3dc(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: How is your question related to Kendo? I don't see anything remotely related to it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It should be something like this  vM.Users.AddRange(result); ? Won't it throw me an error of conversion?

Comment: @Marco well it is, I want to display the list as a column in a KENDO grid. I didn't put the code, because I won't encounter any errors in the view. But if it bothers you that much, I will change the title.

Comment: @GeorgeGreat even if you add Users to `vM`, you are returning `result` to the view. So this won't have any effect.

Comment: No, not if they are both `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var result = (from x in db.Tablewhere x.Id.Value == vM.Id orderby x.GroupId select  x.Name ).ToList();
                    vM.Users=result.ToList();
                    return Json(vM.Users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Solved

Comment: What is the point of that - its identical to `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. And `result` is already `List<T>` so `.ToList()` is pointless